# Symfony 4 Production Mode ErrorHandling Pages Memory Exhausted

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I set my project to `prod` mode in `.env` and everything aside from the custom error pages seem to work.

I have this as my 404 twig template:

```
{# templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig #}
{% include 'builder/layout/header.html.twig' with {'title': '404'} %}

<img src="{{ assets('img/not-found.jpeg') }}" class="img-responsive"
     id="error-not-found-img" />

<div class="http-error-msg-container">
    <h1>404! Page Not Found</h1>
    <p>Don't despair, go back to <a href="{{ path('dashboard') }}">Home</a> and try again.</p>
</div>

{% include 'builder/layout/footer.html.twig' %}
```

and going to a non-existant page (say `/dashboard/giorgoirdjfisejf`) returns a blank page. So I added this to my `index.php` file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

to show the errors and I got this:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/solomon/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/solomon/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/OutOfMemoryException.php on line 1

I'm not quite sure why this causes an error and unable to debug. `var/log/prod.log` doesn't show anything, how do I resolve or better yet, how do I debug?

## update

my prod/monolog.yaml file

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
            excluded_404s:
                # regex: exclude all 404 errors from the logs
                - ^/
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:   console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
```

this was auto-generated and I've made no changes

Comment: Its trying to log something big, so it crash and thats the reason why there is nothing in your prod.log. Try it on your local machine with memory_limit -1 and you could see what it is

Comment: What TYPE of handler?

Comment: in your config yaml for monolog, what type of log handler are you using?

Comment: Try adding `buffer_size: 200` to the handler config

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check file permissions on symfony log files. It looks like monolog catches `permission denied` exception, tries to write it to log and catches same error again and again.

Comment: forgot to actually check the error log, dankes this showed the actual error and I resolved it straight away :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error message was almost identical, except the stack trace always pointed to line 171 in `StreamHandler.php`. The problem was that Composer was run on Windows and the resulting files were copied to a Linux system. This resulted in the incorrect directory separator being used and Symfony then tried to create `/var/www/html/var\log/prod.log` (contains backslash), which obviously fails.

So be sure to run Composer on the same OS on which you will be running the application later.